# How can I set nox player as my expo emulator?

Tags: react-native, emulation, expo, exponent

nox player is very smooth in compare to genymotion. I have very low spec pc when I use genymotion in expo it legs a lot nox player is super smooth.is there any way to set a nox player as expo emulator?

Comment: have you done any research yet? please elaborate.

Answer (score 3):

After some research I got the answer:-

step 1: In Nox player Enable root access in Settings

step 2: Go to settings, go to about tablet and tap build number for 8 times to enable developer options

step 3: Go to developer options and enable "usb debugging"

step 4: Open terminal and type adb connect 127.0.0.1:62001. type adb devices to make sure your emulator is connected.

step 5: Go to your project, type react-native run-android --deviceId 127.0.0.1:62001, waiting for the project to finish compiling, and you will see a red error screen.

step 6: Open the developer menu, Go to Dev Settings → Debug server host for device, Assume your local ip is 192.168.1.121, then type: 192.168.1.121:8081

step 7: Use developer menu to reload your app, then close the app and reopen it.

step 8 : After all this done open expo xde it run your app automatically

Comment: Nox player is 4.4.1ish android version, Expo currently want 5.0 minimum. It is possible that this will not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** This solution works only with expo client. Not with react-native bare-bone.

I don't know if it is the real solution, but this also works.

- First, start your expo project by `expo start` or `npm start`
- After complete startup, you will get a message like `Tunnel ready`.
- Type "s" in the terminal in which the expo is running. It will prompt you to create a new account or log in with an existing account.
- When you signed in or logged in to your account, go to Expo Developer Tools (usually at `localhost:19002`).
- There, you will see an option `send link with email`. Click it and type your email address.
- Now, make sure that you have your mail client and expo app is installed in your nox player.
- Open the email in your emulator and click the link given.

That's it, your app should be running on your nox emulator.